# how can I resize ubuntu partition using gparted?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

I have a dual-boot laptop with Windows 10 and ubuntu 20.04. At first I allocate 26GB space to ubuntu but now I think it is too small, so I want to resize it to 250GB. Now I have two disks, I decide that one for windows and the other for Linux. However, when I first decide to set up dual-boot, I only have one disk so the ubuntu is mounted in the previous disk. Can anybody tell me how to resize it using the new disk and do not influence the ubuntu which I am using?

[image]

[image]

as it shows, I want to merge the nvme0n1p5 and sda2, but I can't do that in gparted, I think probably because they are in different disks, how can I do that?

Comment: You'll need to live-boot in with a flashed ISO.

Comment: I just added more information, could you please say in details?

Comment: About 30GB for `/` on one disk is probably sufficient and a separate partition - or disk for `/home` is advantageous. If you ever need to reinstall Linux, you can then choose to not wipe out your /home partition. You have indicated that you want 250GB for swap - this is madness!

Comment: You cannot resize or move the partition that contains the running Linux. You have to boot from CD/DVD/USB pendrive to do this. You can use a rescue Linux system or an Ubuntu (or other) installation media, see https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install. **But** moving from one disk to a different disk is more difficult. Gparted cannot do this. See e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/741723 For a beginner I suggest to find a local expert that can help you at your location.

Comment: You can move /home to a new partition. Move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2455822&p=14010437#post14010437 Bit more advanced, create a Linux data partition and move your data folders in /home to that data partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk Or combination of both.